# Duplicate log entries with spring boot logback

Tags: spring-boot

In our projects we have a strange problem with duplicate log entries in the log file.

- We have multiple appenders but a single logger.
- If the spring boot application is started on local machine using java -jar the problem is not reproducible.
- The problem occurs only when the application started as a service.

How can i solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurs only if a file appender configured and if the spring boot application started using /etc/init.d/ symlink.

The spring boot's default start script redirects all console logs into the configured log file. 
As a result both the logback logger and start scripts writes in the same file, thus we see duplicate entries in the log file.

Using systemctl (or setting the LOG_FILE or LOG_FOLDER environment variables) will solve this problem.

If you cannot switch to systemd you can set the environment variables so that all stdout&stderr messages redirected to /dev/null:

```
export LOG_FOLDER=/dev
export LOG_FILENAME=null
```